# What happens when I tend treasure boxes?

Tags: brightwood-adventures

I just had a villager finish tending a treasure box, and nothing seemed to happen.

What is supposed to have happened, if anything? Did my game just glitch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this game is really prone to time glitches where it will all of a sudden decide you haven't made any progress towards a question even when you have.

Treasure boxes with give you a number of different things when you open them.